# jquery not change input value from calling ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dom

Problem solved. Check working code on bottom.

first, sorry for my english. If possible pls rewrite my question.

I can not change input value with jquery from calling ajax page.

(jquery version http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js)

My main page is index.php and ajax page is ajax.php. I called ajax.php with

`$.ajax(...`

But after working ajax codes then input value didnt change on index.php.

here is index.php input code

```
<input name="guncel_fiyat" type="hidden" id="guncel_fiyat" value="old value">
```

here is index.php ajax calling code:

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "../ajax.php",
                data: post_edilecek_veri,
                cache: false,
                success: function(donen_veri)
                {
                    some code here;
                }
            }
```

here is ajax.php code (i did try 3 different method but nothing change)

```
$(".guncel_fiyat").val("new value");
```

or

```
$("#guncel_fiyat").val("new value");
```

or

```
$(".guncel_fiyat input").val("new value");
```

after calling ajax then try get new value on index.php but only getting "old value" val.

```
var guncel_fiyat_degeri = $("#guncel_fiyat").val();
alert(guncel_fiyat);
```

HERE IS WORKING CODE

CALL_AJAX.HTML:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function peyfunc() 
{ 
    "use strict";
    var current_price = $("#current_price").val();
    alert ("current_price="+current_price);
    $.ajax(
            {
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#display").html(html);
                }
            }   
    );

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input name="current_price" type="hidden" id="current_price" value="5">
  <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Button"  onclick="peyfunc()">
</form>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX_TEST.PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
test
<script type="text/javascript">
//alert("aaa");
$("#current_price").val("new value");
alert ($("#current_price").val());
</script>
```

Comment: this add  new value `$("#guncel_fiyat").val("new value");`  and this alert url new value `alert($("#guncel_fiyat").val("new value"));`

Comment: upload full code of ajax.php and ajax call sow we can help you,we don't getting what u actually try.

Comment: Now my code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE IS WORKING CODE

CALL_AJAX.HTML:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function peyfunc() 
{ 
    "use strict";
    var current_price = $("#current_price").val();
    alert ("current_price="+current_price);
    $.ajax(
            {
                url: "ajax_test.php",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#display").html(html);
                }
            }   
    );

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <input name="current_price" type="hidden" id="current_price" value="5">
  <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Button"  onclick="peyfunc()">
</form>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX_TEST.PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
test
<script type="text/javascript">
//alert("aaa");
$("#current_price").val("new value");
alert ($("#current_price").val());
</script>
```